# cefsharp: The percentage of the ZoomLevel corresponds？

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a WPF program with an embedded cefsharp browser kernel, and I want to zoom in and out. I checked the example of the website, using the zoomLevel attribute control, but without a definite percentage. When I want to set the percentage of 150%, 300%, etc., how do I set the corresponding zoomLevel? Where can I find this document?

Comment: The answer to this actually lies in `CEF`, remember that `CefSharp` is a wrapper around `CEF`. Here is some discussion surrounding zoom levels on the CEF forums: http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11491 I'd recommend asking on their forums if you would like any further clarification, or adding a `CEF` tag to your post.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answer [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11491).
For me (and for some of the forum members) this worked quite well:

> Scale := 1.2 ^ ZoomLevel;
>   ZoomLevel := LogN(1.2, Scale);